# WiX Toolset Catastrophic failure running light.exe

Tags: wix3.10

When running light.exe on our build server we are now seeing the following error:

> light.exe : error LGHT0001: Catastrophic failure (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED)) [blah.wixproj] build  12-Mar-2019
>   16:07:28       [exec]    build    12-Mar-2019 16:07:28         [exec]
>   Exception Type: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>   build 12-Mar-2019 16:07:28         [exec]    build    12-Mar-2019 16:07:28
>   [exec]   Stack Trace: build   12-Mar-2019 16:07:28         [exec]      at
>   Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Cab.Interop.NativeMethods.CreateCabFinish(IntPtr
>   contextHandle, IntPtr newCabNamesCallBackAddress) build   12-Mar-2019
>   16:07:28       [exec]      at
>   Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Cab.WixCreateCab.Complete(IntPtr
>   newCabNamesCallBackAddress) build 12-Mar-2019 16:07:28         [exec]
>   at
>   Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.CabinetBuilder.CreateCabinet(CabinetWorkItem
>   cabinetWorkItem) build    12-Mar-2019 16:07:28         [exec]      at
>   Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.CabinetBuilder.ProcessWorkItems()

We get nothing useful in the exception message, nor the event logs.  Any suggestions on how to proceed?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this one is really weird, I suspect that it might have something to do with MSI packages - I have bootstrapper, perfectly working with a large number of MSI packages, but one set of packages causes this exception.
Mystery

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've reached CAB size limit 2GB?